# How to enable collaboration on local Cloud9 install?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Me and a friend are collaborating on a project using a Cloud9 SSH project, but we're not happy with the latency. We have tried installing Cloud9 directly on the server, but the collaboration option disappeared.

**Is collaboration possible to enable on a custom Cloud9 installation?** If so, how?

I imagine it's a plugin with some configuration required, so it's left out by default. I can't find anything when Googling though.

---

Edit: I found the collab plugin repo: https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.collab

Doesn't have a README file though, so I'm still just as stuck.

Comment: In regards to latency, please contact support@c9.io and include your username and workspace name.

Comment: @BradyDowling Surely there is no way to avoid the aggregated latency of the communication between the browser and the C9 server, and the C9 server and the SSH server anyway? Wouldn't the best way be to install C9 directly on the server in question? I welcome suggestions

Comment: ah so you're saying that your internet connection is admittedly at fault for that? In that case, a local install would be best so you're right here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the `--collab` flag while launching the server.js

Example:

```
nodejs server.js --collab
```

Comment: Ok that was surprisingly easy... :) It opened up a score of additional issues though, but that's beyond the scope of this question.